Paint events are not triggered in a deployed Qt5 app
I have two Ubuntu 22.04 running in a VM. On the first VM, Qt5 is installed, and I build a Qt5 project with CMake. I can run the executable and everything's fine, until now.
I also prepared a shell script that automatically copies all the necessary libraries and plugins into folders next to the executable. Then, I have a wrapper script, that links those libs and plugins and then runs the executable. Then moving to an "out of the box" Ubuntu 22.04 in another VM, so no Qt or something else is installed.
Here, I face the problem that whenever I change the UI, like using a scrollbar or setting a pixmap to a QLabel, the application does not update the UI properly. E.g., when using a scrollbar, there is smearing of the UI. I have to click-drag at the edge of the window and increase/decrease its size to trigger a paint event, and then everything looks normal.
It seems like there is something missing, like a plugin or a lib. But I have no idea where to start searching.
Here is the shell script that searches for libraries and plugins based on the executable passed as an input argument. Since the shell script also write the wrapper script, you will find it under the "Create Wrapper-Script" section at the end of the script:
#!/bin/bash

QT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins"

# Check if QT_PLUGIN_PATH exists
if [ ! -d "$QT_PLUGIN_PATH" ]; then
  echo "Error: QT_PLUGIN_PATH ($QT_PLUGIN_PATH) does not exist."
  exit 1
fi

# Check if an executable is provided
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <executable>"
  exit 1
fi

#     ##########################################################################
echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Copying Libraries >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
#     ##########################################################################
# Set variables
EXECUTABLE="$1"
LIB_DEST_DIR="./libs"

# Create destination directory if it doesnt exist
mkdir -p "$LIB_DEST_DIR"

# Use ldd to list the libraries and copy them to the destination directory
ldd "$EXECUTABLE" | grep "=> /" | awk '{print $3}' | while read lib; do
  # Extract the filename from the full path
  filename=$(basename "$lib")
  # Copy the library to the destination directory
  echo "Copying $lib to $LIB_DEST_DIR/$filename"
  cp "$lib" "$LIB_DEST_DIR/$filename"
done

echo "Libraries copied successfully."


#     ##########################################################################
echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Copying Plugins >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
#     ##########################################################################
# Variables
BASE_DIR=$(dirname "$EXECUTABLE")  # The directory where the executable is located
PLUGIN_DEST_DIR="$BASE_DIR/plugins"     # Plugins directory next to the executable
LOG_FILE="temp_qt_plugin_log.txt"


# Create the "plugins" directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$PLUGIN_DEST_DIR"

# Enable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS and run the executable to log the plugin search process
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
echo "Running the executable to identify required Qt plugins..."
./"$EXECUTABLE" &> "$LOG_FILE"

echo "Logging plugin search process to $LOG_FILE"

# Extract plugin loading info from log
echo "Identifying required plugins and copying them to $PLUGIN_DEST_DIR..."

# Define a function to copy the plugin to the "plugins" directory
copy_plugin() {
  local plugin_path="$1"
  local plugin_rel_path="${plugin_path#$QT_PLUGIN_PATH/}"  # Strip the QT_PLUGIN_PATH prefix
  local dest_path="$PLUGIN_DEST_DIR/$plugin_rel_path"

  # Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$dest_path")"

  # Copy the plugin
  if [[ -f "$plugin_path" ]]; then
    cp "$plugin_path" "$dest_path"
    echo "Plugin found by $2. Copied: $plugin_path to $dest_path"
  else
    echo "Missing: $plugin_path"
  fi
}

# Parse the log to find plugins and copy them
grep -E "loaded library" "$LOG_FILE" | while read -r line; do
  # Extract the plugin path from the log line
  plugin_path=$(echo "$line" | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')
  
  if [[ -f "$plugin_path" ]]; then
    # Copy the plugin to the plugins directory
    copy_plugin "$plugin_path" "QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS"
  else
    echo "Plugin not found: $plugin_path"
  fi
done

# using strace to capture the system calls related to loading plugins
echo "Running strace to identify plugin-related system calls..."
strace -e trace=open,openat ./"$EXECUTABLE" 2>&1 | grep -E '(platforms|imageformats|plugins).*\.so"$' | while read -r line; do
  file_path=$(echo "$line" | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')
  
  if [[ -f "$file_path" ]]; then
    # Copy the plugin to the plugins directory if found via strace
    copy_plugin "$file_path" "strace"
  else
    echo "Missing plugin via strace: $file_path, line: $line"
  fi
done

# Clean up
echo "Plugin identification and copying complete."

#     ##########################################################################
echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Copying Plugin Dependencies >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
#     ##########################################################################

copy_libraries_for_plugin() {
  local plugin="$1"
  
  plugin=$(realpath "$plugin")
  if [ -f "$plugin" ]; then
    echo "Checking dependencies for plugin: $plugin"

    ldd "$plugin" | grep "=> /" | awk '{print $3}' | while read -r lib; do
      lib=$(realpath "$lib")
      
      if [ -f "$lib" ] && [ ! -f "$LIB_DEST_DIR/$(basename "$lib")" ]; then
        echo "Copying library: $lib to $LIB_DEST_DIR"
        cp "$lib" "$LIB_DEST_DIR" 2>/dev/null || echo "Failed to copy library: $lib"
      fi
    done
  fi
}

find "$PLUGIN_DEST_DIR" -type f -name "*.so*" | while read -r plugin; do
  copy_libraries_for_plugin "$plugin"
done
echo "> Library copying complete."


#     ##########################################################################
echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Creating Symbolic Library Links >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
#     ##########################################################################
cd "$LIB_DEST_DIR" || { echo "Directory $LIB_DEST_DIR not found."; exit 1; }


# Loop over each file with the ".so.X.Y" pattern
for lib in *.so.*.*; do
  # Skip files that have a patch version (e.g., libX.so.5.15.2)
  if [[ "$lib" =~ \.so\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]]; then
    continue
  fi
  # Extract the major, minor, and patch version numbers
  major_version=$(echo "$lib" | sed -n 's/.*\.so\.\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/p')
  minor_version=$(echo "$lib" | sed -n 's/.*\.so\.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)/\1/p')

  # Generate the base name for the major version
  base_name_major="lib$(echo "$lib" | sed 's/\(.*\.so\)\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/\1.'"$major_version"'/')"
  # Create a symbolic link from libX.so.major to libX.so.major.minor
  if [ -f "$base_name_major" ]; then
    rm "$base_name_major"
  fi
  if [ ! -L "$base_name_major" ]; then
    echo "Creating symlink: $base_name_major -> $lib"
    ln -s "$lib" "$base_name_major"
  else
    echo "Symlink $base_name_major already exists"
  fi
done

# Loop over each file with the ".so.X.Y.Z" pattern
for lib in *.so.*.*.*; do
  # Extract the major, minor, and patch version numbers
  major_version=$(echo "$lib" | sed -n 's/.*\.so\.\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/\1/p')
  minor_version=$(echo "$lib" | sed -n 's/.*\.so\.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/p')
  patch_version=$(echo "$lib" | sed -n 's/.*\.so\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)/\1/p')

  # Generate the base names for each level
  base_name_major="$(echo "$lib" | sed 's/\(.*\.so\)\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/\1.'"$major_version"'/')"
  base_name_major_minor="$(echo "$lib" | sed 's/\(.*\.so\)\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/\1.'"$major_version.$minor_version"'/')"

  # Create a symbolic link from libX.so.major.minor to libX.so.major.minor.patch
  if [ -f "$base_name_major_minor" ]; then
    rm "$base_name_major_minor"
  fi
  if [ ! -L "$base_name_major_minor" ]; then
    echo "Creating symlink: $base_name_major_minor -> $lib"
    ln -s "$lib" "$base_name_major_minor"
  else
    echo "Symlink $base_name_major_minor already exists"
  fi

  # Create a symbolic link from libX.so.major to libX.so.major.minor
  if [ -f "$base_name_major" ]; then
    rm "$base_name_major"
  fi
  if [ ! -L "$base_name_major" ]; then
    echo "Creating symlink: $base_name_major -> $base_name_major_minor"
    ln -s "$base_name_major_minor" "$base_name_major"
  else
    echo "Symlink $base_name_major already exists"
  fi
done
echo "> Symbolic link creation complete."

cd ..
echo "Clean up..."
echo "... delete $EXECUTABLE log files."
rm -r ./Log/
echo "... unset debug environment variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS."
unset QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS
echo "... delete temporary files." 
rm $LOG_FILE

echo "Clean up done." 

#     ##########################################################################
echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Create Wrapper-Script >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
#     ##########################################################################
cat << 'EOF' > run"$EXECUTABLE".sh
#!/bin/bash

EXECUTABLE=TestExec

# Variables
LIB_DIR="./libs"      # Directory where libraries are located
PLUGIN_DIR="./plugins" # Directory where plugins are located

# Check if the executable exists
if [ ! -x "$EXECUTABLE" ]; then
  echo "Error: Executable ($EXECUTABLE) does not exist or is not executable."
  exit 1
fi

# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the directory with the libraries, but preload the system's libstdc++
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LIB_DIR:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

# Preload system libstdc++
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6"

# Set QT_PLUGIN_PATH and QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH to include the directories with Qt plugins
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH="$PLUGIN_DIR:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH"
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE="xcb"
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM="xcb"
# Run the executable
echo "Running $EXECUTABLE..."
exec ./"$EXECUTABLE"
EOF

chmod +x run"$EXECUTABLE".sh

echo "> Creating wrapper script done."

#     ##########################################################################
echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Compress Deployed Application >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
#     ##########################################################################
echo "Compressing to $EXECUTABLE.tar.gz ..."
tar -czf "$EXECUTABLE.tar.gz" *
echo "> Compressing completed."

I have made a test: the application should set a pixmap to a QLabel depending on the connection state between the application and an other device.
Right now, It did not properely update the UI. If I resize the window, it shows the new connection state. Then I have forced a repaint after the connection state changed in the code, and now it works fine. So something's missing that recognizes and executes the repaint events.
Where are those events triggered?
Note: on the build system, everything works fine.
